# How can to fix IndexError: index 1212 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1212

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am learning Machine Learning tutorials.But I encountered unexpected trouble.I tried more methods for solving error.But I couldn't solve.

```
def tur_dagilim_grafigi(turler=("bradypus_variegatus_0",
                                "microryzomys_minutus_0")):
    """
    Tür dağılımın grafiği
    """
    if len(turler)>2:
        print("Not:İkiden fazla tür sağlandığında sadece ilk ikisi kullanacak")
    t0=time()
    #Baskılanmış veriyi yükle
    veri=fetch_species_distributions()


    xekseni,yekseni=construct_grids(veri)
    #X,Y koordinatları içinde eksen
    X,Y=np.meshgrid(xekseni,yekseni[::-1])
    #Her tür için bir demet oluştur.
    BV_demet=demet_turleri_olustur(turler[0],veri.train,veri.test,veri.coverages,xekseni,yekseni)
    MM_demet=demet_turleri_olustur(turler[1],veri.train,veri.test,veri.coverages,xekseni,yekseni)
    #Değerlendirme için arkaplan puanları

    np.random.seed(13)
    arkaplan_puanlari=np.c_[np.random.randint(low=0,high=veri.Ny,size=10000),
                            np.random.randint(low=0,high=veri.Nx,size=10000)].T
    #Kapsamaya ait tüm ölçümlerin etki kullanımını yapacağız.
    #Kara puanları-Bu bize kara ve su arasında karar vermemize yardım edecektir.
    kara_referansi=veri.coverages[6]
    for a,tur in enumerate([BV_demet,MM_demet]):
        print("_"*80)
        print("Türlerin dağılımı modellemesi %s" % tur.name)
        ortalama=tur.cov_train.mean(axis=0)
        sapma=tur.cov_train.std(axis=0)
        sapmafarki=(tur.cov_train-ortalama)/sapma
        print("-Tek sınıf SVM uydur",end='')
        siniflandirma=svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1,kernel="rbf",gamma=0.5)
        siniflandirma.fit(sapmafarki)
        print("yapıldı")
        #Güney Amerika harita arazisi
        plt.subplot(1,2,a+1)
        if tabanharitasi:
            print("Kıyı çizgisi arazisi taban haritası kullanıyor")
            l=Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=Y.min(),
                      urcrnlat=Y.max(),
                      llcrnlon=X.min(),
                      urcrnrlon=X.max(),
                      resolution='c')
            l.drawcoastlines()
            l.drawcountries()
        else:
            print("kapsamdan kıyı çizgisi arazisi")
            plt.contour(X,Y,kara_referansi,levels=[-9998],colors='k',linestyles='solid')
            plt.xticks([])
            plt.yticks([])
        print("tür dağılımını tahmin etme")
        #Eğitilmiş veriyi kullanarak tür dağılımını tahmin edelim.
        K=np.ones((veri.Nx,veri.Ny),dtype=np.float64)
        #Biz sadece kara puanlarını tahmin edeceğiz.
        idx=np.where(kara_referansi >= -9999)
        kapsam_karasi=veri.coverages[:,idx[0],idx[1]].T
        tahmin=siniflandirma.decision_function((kapsam_karasi-ortalama) / sapma)
        K *=tahmin.min()
        K[idx[0],idx[1]]=tahmin
        seviyeler=np.linspace(K.min(),K.max(),25)
        K[kara_referansi==-9999]=-9999
        plt.contourf(X, Y, K, levels=seviyeler, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
        plt.colorbar(format='%.2f')
        #Eğitilmiş/sınama puanlarının saçılımı
        plt.scatter(turler.asf_egitim['dd long'],turler.asf_egitim['dd lat'],s=2**2,c='yellow',marker='*',label='eğitim')
        plt.scatter(turler.asf_sinama['dd long'],turler.asf_egitim['dd lat'],s=2**2,c='blue',marker='^',label='sınama')
        plt.legend()
        plt.title(tur.name)
        plt.axis('eşit')
        arkaplan_tahmini=K[arkaplan_puani[0],arkaplan_puani[1]]
        tahmin_sinama=siniflandirma.decision_function((turler.X-ortalama) / sapma)
        r=np.r_[tahmin_sinama,arkaplan_tahmini]
        sayi=np.r_[np.ones(tahmin_sinama.shape),np.zeros(arkaplan_tahmini.shape)]
        fpr,tpr,esikler=metrics.roc_curve(sayi,r)
        roc_auc=metrics.auc(fpr,tpr)
        plt.text('Alan ROC eğrisi altında:%f' % roc_auc)
        print("\nZaman sarkması:%.2fs" % (time() - t0))
```

Comment: Just from the error: `1212` is exactly one to high for a `1212` axis. Counting starts at zero.

Comment: I understood this problem.I typed from Scikit-Learn samples.Sample's author didn't influence this problem.

Comment: Any chance you can reduce that to the minimum amount of functional code that reproduces the problem? Please read [mcve].

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k), [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)